# How to wrap a spiral around an object?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a spiral wrap around a bent object. Or at least, bend the spiral itself to be placed and scaled accordingly.

The example here is of the tights, two seperate spirals mirrored and merged, wrapping around this characters leg. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Is it for a still or animate character? Here is a way to do it for a still character, I hope someone will give you a solution if you need to animate your character:

- Model your character.
- Create a bezier curve that loosely wraps around the shape of the leg. Put the bezier origin point on its bottom vertex, check its direction so that it goes up.
- Give your bezier a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the leg as *Target*, enable the fourth displaying option of the modifier (*Apply this and all preceding deformation modifiers...*).
- Create a cylinder, subdivide it horizontally and put it on the origin point of the bezier.
- Give it an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier, enable the *Merge* option of the Array, and choose the bezier as the *Object* of the *Curve* modifier. Play with the parameters so that it follows the bezier correctly. Give also your cylinder a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Play with the Offset of the bezier *Shrinkwrap* modifier to tighten the pipe along the leg.

[image]